# CSS Selector :not() only working in Safari

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In Safari (newest Version of El Capitan OS X) and in iOS 9 following code works, but I am uncertain why only here and not in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X.

```
<section id="content" class='special-content'>
...
<article>
    <ul>
        <li>Headline
        <ul>
            <li>Explanation 1</li>
            <li>Explanation 2</li>
            <li>Explanation 3</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Here is the problematic thing:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .special-content ul:not(ul li ul) { display: table; }
    .special-content ul li:not(ul li ul li) {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-table;
        border-spacing: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid #469A79;
    }
    .special-content ul li:not(ul li ul li) { margin-bottom: 0}
}

.special-content ul li:not(ul li ul li) { color: red; }
.special-content ul li:not(ul li ul li) ul li { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about `:not` with multiple selector.

```
.special-content ul li:not(ul):not(li):not(ul):not(li){ color: green; }
```

Ps: if this approach doesn't satisfy your problem. You should add `class` so you can generalize the `ul li` selector.

Comment: Perhaps you need to read about it too - I'm not sure you understand what `li:not(ul):not(li):not(ul):not(li)` actually means.